# extjs6 theming guide - mixing not being recognized

Tags: css, extjs, mixins, extjs6

I am following the ExtJS6 theming guide and creating my first mixin on a panel.
I've created a theme in packages/local/my-classic-theme2/sass/var/panel/Panel.scss
The panel is not being changed when I run and I am getting the following errors. in the panel.scss it says undeclared mixin.

sencha app watch error in picture[image]

am I missing a step?

```
@include extjs-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'highlight-framed',
    $ui-header-background-color: red,
    $ui-border-color: red,
    $ui-header-border-color: red,
    $ui-body-border-color: red,
    $ui-border-width: 5px,
    $ui-border-radius: 5px,
    $ui-header-color: white
);
```

and I put this on the actual panel

```
ui: 'highlight',
frame: true,
```

Comment: that definitely did something... the panel header got smaller but everything is still the default blue.  even though I stated red.  is there a reason? (I put the mixin above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

Created a new app with the following command

`sencha -sdk <path to ext 6.0.2> generate app -ext MyApp MyTestApp`

`cd MyTestApp`

`sencha generate theme --extend theme-classic my-classic-theme2`

Created the folder `panel` inside `packages/local/my-classic-theme2/sass/src` and created a file `Panel.scss` inside that folder.

Edited that file and pasted your code as is:

```
@include extjs-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'highlight-framed',
    $ui-header-background-color: red,
    $ui-border-color: red,
    $ui-header-border-color: red,
    $ui-body-border-color: red,
    $ui-border-width: 5px,
    $ui-border-radius: 5px,
    $ui-header-color: white
);
```

Edited the `classic/src/view/main/Main.js` file and replaced the items block with this:

```
items: [{
    title: 'Home',
    iconCls: 'fa-home',
    // The following grid shares a store with the classic version's grid as well!
    items: [{
        xtype: 'mainlist'
    }]
}, {
    title: 'Users',
    iconCls: 'fa-user',
    items : [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        frame: true,
        ui: 'highlight',
        title: 'Testing my highlight panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Foo',
            value: 'Bar'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

And finally edited `app.json` and made sure my `"theme"` is pointing to `my-classic-theme2`

Ran `sencha app watch` and went to http://localhost:1841

My Users tab displayed the panel with red title like it should.

[image: highlight ui]